# untrusted enterprise developer alert

Tags: ios, mdm

There is an untrusted enterprise developer alert displaying with the description "until this developer has been trusted, their enterprise apps will not be available for users".

I just tried multiple options to check the trust option in settings but there is no trust button.

A lot of users reported that they are not able to trust the apps, which causing an issue. Can someone please suggest how can we fix this?

Can we test some options from MDM, to manually install the enterprise certificates pushed to devices.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your  developer account has an issue in developer.apple.com . It takes time that Apple make you a valid and known developer. If you have enrolled in the Enterprise program (which costs $299) you must wait until you get verified by Apple.